# Как посчитать некоторое значение (доллары) (поле 2*), после разделения поля (поле 1*) на 2 отдельные категории?

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL

Имею таблицу, в ней поля:

1. категория фильма;
2. цена аренды фильма, рубли;

Разбила поле 1 на 2 подкатегории: для взрослых, для всех методом CASE
и мне теперь нужно посчитать, сколько составляла суммарная цена аренды подкатегорий "для взрослых" и "для всех" с группировкой по новым двум подкатегориям.

```
SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN 'категория' LIKE '%такая%' THEN 'для взрослых'
          WHEN 'категория' LIKE '%такая%' THEN 'для всех'
      END AS new_category,
      SUM(цена аренды фильма)
FROM фильмы
GROUP BY new_category;
```

Должно выйти что-то типа так:

---

- для взрослых: 100000 рублей (общая сумма аренды фильмов)
- для всех: 120000 рублей (общая сумма аренды фильмов)

А тренажёр мне пишет, что не совпадает с ожидаемым значением. Верно ли, что  я что-то делаю неправильно и пишу неправильный запрос?
Если вопрос не корректный, удалю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сгруппировать данные по вашему условию:

```
SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN 'категория' LIKE '%такая%' THEN 'для взрослых'
          WHEN 'категория' LIKE '%такая%' THEN 'для всех'
      END AS new_category,
      SUM(цена аренды фильма)
FROM фильмы
GROUP BY CASE
          WHEN 'категория' LIKE '%такая%' THEN 'для взрослых'
          WHEN 'категория' LIKE '%такая%' THEN 'для всех'
      END;
```

Или можно вывести данные в одну строку

```
SELECT
      sum(CASE
          WHEN 'категория' LIKE '%такая%' THEN фильмы.цена_аренды
      END)  'для взрослых',
      sum(CASE
          WHEN 'категория' LIKE '%такая%' THEN фильмы.цена_аренды
      END)  'для всех'
FROM фильмы
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, но не принимает, я пробовала и так и так. Видимо, я не понимаю условия задачи, что ли, попробую ещё подумать.

Comment: Возможно стоит точно написать условия. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, добавив условия(Что надо сделать, какие данные, какие данные ожидаются).

Comment: Вы совершенно верно меня поправили, а ошибка была в том, что я не до конца поняла смысл задачи и соответственно - не верно искала решение. Спасибо